# Accessing Instance Variables in Helper Classes

Tags: java

**Disclaimer:** I come from a dynamic language background (Ruby) and I'm trying to level up my skills in Java. I fear with my problem here I'm thinking too much in the context of Ruby and would appreciate some pointers.

**Problem:**

I want to see how I can have a helper class know about the existence of a WebDriver instance without having to pass the instance around all the time. The reason I'm trying to avoid that is because it leads to extra method arguments and less fluent test writing.

**Context:**

I have a test case (`LoginIT.java`) that looks like this:

```
package com.testerstories.learning.symbiote;

import static com.testerstories.learning.helpers.Selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class LoginIT {
  WebDriver driver;

  @BeforeTest
  public void startBrowser() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void quitBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void loginAsAdmin() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:9292");

    withElement("open").click();

    waitForPresence("username");

    withElement("username").sendKeys("admin");
    withElement("password").sendKeys("admin");
    withElement("login-button").submit();

    waitForPresence("notice");

    assertThat(withElement("notice", "className"), equalTo("You are now logged in as admin."));
  }
}
```

The key methods to note here are the calls to `withElement` and `waitForPresence`. These are defined on the Selenium class that I created and reference via the static import at the top.

Here is `Selenium.java` which contains that logic:

```
package com.testerstories.learning.helpers;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium {
  public static WebElement withElement(String identifier, String locator) {
    switch (locator) {
        case "className":
            return driver.findElement(By.className(identifier));
        default:
            return withElement(identifier);
    }
  }

  public static WebElement withElement(String identifier) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
  }

  public static void waitForPresence(String identifier, String locator) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 500);

    switch (locator) {
        case "className":
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(identifier)));
        default:
            waitForPresence(identifier);
    }
  }

  public static void waitForPresence(String identifier) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 500);
      wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(identifier)));

  }
}
```

The key problem here are the lines that reference `driver`. When these methods were defined in `LoginIT.java` that wasn't an issue because WebDriver is defined there in the `driver` instance.

I do know that one answer to my problem is that I could just pass the WebDriver instance to each method. So, for example, I could use this method signature with `withElement`:

```
public static WebElement withElement(WebDriver driver, String identifier)
```

I'm adding another argument to pass in the WebDriver instance. But that means my test logic has to look like this:

```
withElement(driver, "username").sendKeys("admin");
withElement(driver, "password").sendKeys("admin");
withElement(driver, "login-button").submit();
```

Not the end of the world but it's less fluent and it just seems like there should be a better way.

**Question:**

Is there a better way?

Or am I in fact on the right track and should just accept that if I want the helper methods to be separate from the tests the `driver` reference must be passed in? And thus accept the slightly more verbose test statements?

**Other Thought:**

The only other thing I can immediately think of is that I create yet a third class that represents just WebDriver itself. This third class is then used by both my test (`LoginIt.java`) and my test helper (`Selenium.java`). I'm not sure how best to implement that but I'm also not sure if going that route makes sense.

I say that because it seems if I do that, I'm simply creating a class to wrap the creation of a WebDriver instance. So I have to create a class to then get an instance of that class so that I can create an instance of WebDriver. It seems like I'm adding complexity ... but maybe not. Hence my quest for pointers.

Comment: One idea is to instantiate an instance of your helper class for a specific driver, initialize it with that driver, and then methods internally can perform some action on its own driver.

Comment: I might actually consider inheritance here. A base test class that defines these methods and sets up its driver that your other test classes extend, if you can make that work with your test tool.

Comment: I was considering inheritance. But then I wondered if I shouldn't do an interface. And then I got totally mixed up. I keep thinking that my logic of `driver = new FirefoxDriver` (currently in the `startBrowser()` method) could instead go in some sort of third class. So the `@BeforeTest` method would then use that class to instantiate the `driver` instance. So my thought then is that the helper method could also use this class to get the driver reference. But, key thing, it shouldn't create a new driver each time. So I have to recognize when a driver has already been created.

Comment: From a pragmatic perspective, it looks to me like the driver is instance data on the test class. You could try to move it somewhere else, but ultimately, the test class really needs to manage it. Additionally, this management should be the same across all the test classes using Selenium, right? So inheritance might actually be a good choice. You have a common set of base logic used by all your test classes, and you need to extend it with particular tests. The place this might break down is if several different test classes are doing very different things with the lifetime of the driver.

Comment: I would think of this as a choice between paradigms. You can go the OOP route and use inheritance because of the nature of the shared logic and the way the instance data needs to be managed, or you can go a more procedural/functional route and just pass it around without worrying about the extra argument. I used to be wary of the procedural/functional approach, but I've come to realize there's actually nothing really wrong with it.

Comment: Right, and that's where I fear my Ruby thinking is infecting my Java thinking. I see your point about having some base class. It is a good point that the test class has to "manage" the browser driver because each test class can be run independently. That said, the Selenium class isn't really managing it per se, it just has to use the instance to have a context to run the `wait` and `findElement` methods on. But even with a base test class, that driver instance still has to get to the helper class. And the helper class shouldn't derive from the base test class, I would think.

Comment: Okay, I sort of see something that might be in line with what you are saying. If I had a `Driver.java` class that was responsible for instantiating the driver, then my test class would look like `public class LoginIT extends Driver`. So then my test class _and_ my helper class could get this instance by `driver = Driver.createDriver();`. Here the `createDriver()` would be a method that does just that: creates a driver and returns that. I'm starting to see a glimmer of a solution but I can't type it fully in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely certain if this solution follows best design practices, but here is what I ended up doing. (Note: I changed from TestNG to JUnit but other than that, everything is functionally equivalent.)

I created a `Driver.java` class:

```
package com.testerstories.learning.helpers;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Driver {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (null == driver) {
           driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public void quitDriver() {
        if (null != driver) {
            driver.quit();
            driver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

So this class is responsible for creating a driver instance and getting rid of that instance. It checks if the driver is null before creating so it won't keep creating new instances. Here I'm hard-coding a new instance of Firefox. Eventually I would have to make this class create new browser drivers based on what the user wants, but baby steps first.

Then I created `DriverFactory.java` which looks like this:

```
package com.testerstories.learning.helpers;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class DriverFactory {
    private static Driver driver;

    @Before
    public void createDriver() {
        driver = new Driver();
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver.getDriver();
    }

    @After
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quitDriver();
    }
}
```

This factory is used to create the driver instances. Notice the `@Before` and `@After` annotations. So this is where the tests have to rely on the driver factory. So what this means is that my tests now inherit the `DriverFactory`, whose responsibility is to provide an actual driver instance. So my `LoginIT.java` test now changes to this (continuing to use Jeremiah's provided solution as well):

```
package com.testerstories.learning.symbiote;

import com.testerstories.learning.helpers.DriverFactory;
import com.testerstories.learning.helpers.Selenium;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

public class LoginIT extends DriverFactory {
    WebDriver driver;
    Selenium selenium;

    @Test
    public void loginAsAdmin() {
        driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        selenium = new Selenium(driver);

        driver.get("http://localhost:9292");

        selenium.withElement("open").click();

        selenium.waitForPresence("username");

        selenium.withElement("username").sendKeys("admin");
        selenium.withElement("password").sendKeys("admin");
        selenium.withElement("login-button").submit();

        selenium.waitForPresence("notice", "className");

        assertThat(selenium.withElement("notice", "className").getText(), equalTo("You are now logged in as admin."));
    }
}
```

I'm still doing some (all?) of the things that jpmc26 was concerned about and I can't honestly say I'm doing this well. But this does work.

If anyone has any thoughts -- particularly critical ones -- I'm most open to hearing them. As mentioned in my original question, I'm attempting to get better at Java after many, many years as a Ruby programmer. It's been rough going, to say the least.

Comment: First thing I notice is that you've moved the Before and After to your DriverFactory implementation.  I believe that the junit framework will only scan the test class for those annotations, so I don't believe that will work as you may intend.  Second, the function of your Driver class seems to be just to create and destroy the WebDriver, and the function of your DriverFactory is to create and destroy your Driver class.  I think it would be more clear to remove the 'middle man' and just have your DriverFactory maintain your WebDriver and remove your 'Driver' implementation.

Comment: Be wary of the use of 'static'. Local tests will probably be in a single-threaded.  If you use a build tool like maven/surefire you may end up executing in an multithreaded environment.  When you go to use the 'static' modifier I would suggest asking yourself "what will happen when two (or more) threads act on this  simultaneously?"   I've found that a single WebDriver used in multiple concurrent tests takes special handling to ensure that the commands executed are in the correct context. I would avoid 'static' usages unless it's something stateless, like  a String, but that may just be me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I appreciate them as I continue learning. So far the annotations where I have them seem to be working. But I'll be watchful for issues. As far as the two classes: I agree. It did strike me as wrong initially. (It may still be wrong.) The reason I did it is because the driver factory will eventually handle threads. So I think `Driver` is going to morph into a `DriverThread` class. Still working that idea out.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative may be to allow your Selenium class to be initialized.  Rather than having the methods be static, you can require the WebDriver reference in the class constructor.

```
package com.testerstories.learning.helpers;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Selenium {
    private final WebDriver driver;
    public Selenium(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.driver = webDriver;
    }

    public WebElement withElement(String identifier, String locator) {
        switch (locator) {
            case "className":
                return driver.findElement(By.className(identifier));
            default:
                return withElement(identifier);
        }
    }

    public WebElement withElement(String identifier) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id(identifier));
    }

    public void waitForPresence(String identifier, String locator) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 500);

        switch (locator) {
            case "className":
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(identifier)));
            default:
                waitForPresence(identifier);
        }
    }

    public void waitForPresence(String identifier) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 500);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(identifier)));

    }
}
```

Your LoginIT.java would then initialize the reference with in the @Before along with the driver, and change the formerly static calls to the instance you stood up:

```
package com.testerstories.learning.symbiote;

import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.testerstories.learning.helpers.Selenium;

public class LoginIT {
  WebDriver driver;
  Selenium selenium;

  @BeforeTest
  public void startBrowser() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    selenium = new Selenium(driver);
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void quitBrowser() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void loginAsAdmin() {
    driver.get("http://localhost:9292");

    selenium.withElement("open").click();

    selenium.waitForPresence("username");

    selenium.withElement("username").sendKeys("admin");
    selenium.withElement("password").sendKeys("admin");
    selenium.withElement("login-button").submit();

    selenium.waitForPresence("notice");

    assertThat(selenium.withElement("notice", "className"), equalTo("You are now logged in as admin."));
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's definitely interesting. I tried something similar to what you did with the `Selenium` class ... but I didn't remove the `static` and so I was getting issues with the instance being called in a non-static context. But I see how your approach avoids that problem. Maybe I got too stuck on the `static` aspect of this. I'll play around with this but it certainly looks promising.

Comment: The thing I don't like about this is that the diver is now shared across two instances. This feels messy. There's no clear "owner" of the driver that's supposed to decide what to do with it. You're not really changing the nature of the problem. You're just hiding the argument on all the methods as an instance field, and now you have shared state across two classes. But that's just my opinion. This isn't uncommon. One way to solve that is let this new class own it (and not store it in the test class), but then you need to either duplicate all its existing methods or make the driver public.